# What does the digit after .so in library filenames mean?

Tags: linux, unix, libraries

It doesn't seem to be version, here's an example
name: libcurl.so.4.3.0 
version 7.40

```
me@pc:/somefirmware/extracted/lib$ strings libcurl.so.4.3.0 | grep -i "libcurl"
libcurl.so.4
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
# Fatal libcurl error
Protocol "%s" not supported or disabled in libcurl
CLIENT libcurl 7.40.0
CLIENT libcurl 7.40.0
CLIENT libcurl 7.40.0
libcurl/7.40.0
Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands `identity', `deflate' and `gzip' content encodings.
A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
A libcurl function was given a bad argument
An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
libcurl is now using a weak random seed!
```

A second questions would be how to retrieve the correct version number but I have the feeling that it might be impossible (to do it in 100% of the cases).
Here you can get it with strings but on other libraries it will yield 10 different versions for example

Answer (score 1):

A ".so" (Shared Object) is a library. As such it provides a defined interface to programs linking against it to make use of the functionality provided by the library, also called an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). In shared objects this API is versioned, so that programs using the library can use a version that they are compatible with. See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work) on "Unix & Linux".

The library version you mentioned can be independent from the API version. The library version would describe the code that makes up the functionality of the library, the implementation. It might get increased when bugs are fixed or algorithms get optimized. But at the same time the API may stay stable, which means that the function names and their parameters do not change, so the API version stays the same.

The digit after the .so describes the API version.